# Proving that the sequence $a_{n}= \frac{1}{n}$ ($n$ odd) and $\frac{3}{n}$ ($n$ even) converges.

Tags: convergence-divergence, proof-writing

I need to prove that the sequence ${(a_{n})}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $a_{ n }=\begin{cases} 1/n,\ n\ odd \\ 3/n,\ n\ even \end{cases}$ converges.

––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––
If a sequence ${(a_{n})}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is **decreasing** and is **bounded from below**, the sequence converges.

A sequence of real numbers $(a_{n})$ **converges to** a real number $L$ if, for all $ε >\ 0$, there exists a natural number $N$ such that for all $n\ge N$ we have $\left|a_{n}-L\right|<\ ε$.
––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––––

Show that ${(a_{n})}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is **decreasing**:

$a_{n+1}-a_{n}=\begin{cases}\cfrac{1}{n+1}-\cfrac{3}{n}=\cfrac{n-3(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=\cfrac{-2n-3}{n(n+1)}< 0 \quad for \quad n≥1 \\\cfrac{3}{n+1}-\cfrac{1}{n}=\cfrac{3n-(n+1)}{n(n+1)}=\cfrac{2n-1}{n(n+1)} \ngtr  0 \quad only \ when \quad n\rightarrow  \infty \end{cases}$

...

...

...

???

Comment: The sequence is not decreasing, even for large $n$.  If $n$ is odd then $a_n=\frac 1n<\frac 3{n+1}=a_{n+1}$ since $\frac {n+1}n<3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the sequence $b_n=\frac{3}{n}$ then $a_n\leq b_n$ for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$. It is easy to see that $b_n$ converges, now use this to show that $a_n$ converges too.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this theorem useful.

Theorem on covering by subsequences:

Suppose a sequence $(a_n)$ is given, and $b_n=a_{f(n)}$ and $c_n=a_{g(n)}$ are subsequences, where $f,g$ are increasing functions $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{N}\ $. Suppose also that
$\mathbb{N}=\{f(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}\cup\{g(n):n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ and $(b_n)$ and $(c_n)$ both converge to the same limit $L\in\mathbb{R}$. Then $(a_n)$ converges to $L$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_{ n }=\begin{cases} \dfrac{1}{n},\ n\ odd \\ \dfrac{3}{n},\ n\ even \end{cases}$

$a_n$ is a Cauchy sequence because for any $\varepsilon>0$ if $n,m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have

$\left|a_n-a_m\right|\le\dfrac{2}{n}$ and for $m,n>N=\dfrac{2}{\varepsilon}$ we have

$\left|a_n-a_m\right|<\varepsilon$

A Cauchy sequence always converges in $\mathbb{R}$ because it is a complete metric space, so $\{a_n\}$ converges

*QED*